# How to configure SonarQube search for Names/Keys that do NOT contains strings

Tags: sonarqube

I have some searches for projects in SonarQube that are like this...

Date > "2014-01-01"
Name Contains > "ProjectBear"

What I would like is

Date > "2014-01-01" 
Name Contains > "ProjectBear"
Key DOES NOT Contains > "customerA"

Is this possible in the free/standard SonarQube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not got an "Proper" answer for this, but I have created a GreaseMonkey script to hide the modules I dont need to care about at the moment.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://10.187.72.999:9000/measures/filter/4?display=list
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {
  // Note, jQ replaces $ to avoid conflicts.
  jQ('a[href$="28555"]').parent().parent().remove(); //projectA
  jQ('a[href$="20094"]').parent().parent().remove(); //projectB
  jQ('a[href$="21139"]').parent().parent().remove(); //projectC

//  alert("There are " + jQ('a').length + " links on this page.");
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.
By the way there's only one unique version of SonarQube that is open source.